# Composer does not find my forked repository declared on a custom package's "repository" settings

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I'm currently developing my own composer packages, but they failed trying to execute `composer update`.

This is my root **composer.json**:

```
{
    ...
    "repositories": {
        "bar": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "packages/pinnokkio/bar",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
             }
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        ...
        "pinnokkio/bar": "@dev"
    },
    ...
}
```

This means, package **pinnokkio/bar** should be installed. And package **pinnokkio/bar** requires **pinnokkio/foo** as a dependency.

**composer.json** of **pinnokkio/bar**:

```
{
    "name": "pinnokkio/bar",
    ...
    "repositories": {
        "foo": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../foo",
            "options": {
                "symlink": true
            }
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "pinnokkio/foo": "@dev"
    },
    ...
}
```

**composer.json** of **pinnokkio/foo**:

```
{
    "name": "pinnokkio/foo",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0"
    },
    ...
}
```

All in all, in my main **composer.json**, I'm going to require a package that requires **pinnokkio/foo** to run. And further upcoming packages all require **pinnokkio/foo** in order to run, but unfortunately, I'm getting this error trying to execute `composer update`. All packages are located in `<root>/packages/`:

```
 Problem 1
    - pinnokkio/bar[dev-feature-modules, dev-master] require pinnokkio/foo@dev -> could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package nam
e.
    - Root composer.json requires pinnokkio/bar@dev -> satisfiable by pinnokkio/bar[dev-feature-modules, dev-master].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `repositories` key is only read on the root `composer.json`.

As explained on the [docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories):

> Repositories are not resolved recursively. You can only add them to your main composer.json. Repository declarations of dependencies' composer.jsons are ignored.

Resolving `repositories` recursively would be problematic. If multiple packages declared different repositories that included the same package, how would composer know which to use?

Also, this would open the door for dependencies hijacking your system by providing alternate repositories for known packages, and you'd end up installing untrusted packages in your system.

If you are installing multiple packages from a custom repositories, all the custom repositories need to be declared on the root configuration file.

Comment: Great explanation. Is there any way to add a repository even if the given path does not exist? Like optional, because I'm getting the following error trying to add a non-existing:  "The `url` supplied for the path (packages/pinnokkio/something) repository does not exist"

Comment: Well, I don't think there can't be a better answer because your answer is clear to me and makes much sense.